# Customize incoming fax header Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, fax, freepbx

I'm using default fax app of freePBX, now it can receive the incoming fax via sip trunk. 
But I have the concern: **Is there any way to change/customize the incoming fax header?** 
very appreciate any your suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, as "fax header" is ambiguous. Fax is either delivered over the audio stream or is negotiated as a T.38 UDPTL image stream. What specifically are you looking to manipulate?

Comment: <br> Thanks Matt Jordan, <br/>

Comment: Thanks Matt Jordan, I wanna change some information on header of fax page: From, To, Date,..., . Can we able to change ?

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 variables which you want modify

```
exten => s,1,Set(FAXOPT(localstationid)=My home fax)
exten => s,2,Set(FAXOPT(headerinfo)=Received fax at 1234567890)
```

Just experement with both and see result.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Function_FAXOPT

Comment: Thanks arheops, but it doesn't work with incoming fax ?